firebase dynamic links alternative - route users to the correct store for their device from a single link click
For a Flutter project app, is there a way to have a single link to redirect users to the app page in the correct store, rather than firebase dynamic links as it is deprecated.
EDIT: Firebase dynamic Links SDK for flutter provides a way to generate deep link programmatically. Its better to have an alternative provides the same features.
I read firebase dynamic links migration guide (available on link) and its said obviously that the single link feature isn't supported.

You can use https://www.branch.io/

I think it is a paid service.

Yes, it is a paid service.

You can try https://www.appsflyer.com/ it's free.

Yes, I have just tried appsflyer. it is good, but it lacks a critical feature which firebase dynamic links provides: to be able to generate deep link programatically. It only allow creating deep link via its dashboard.

https://dynalinks.app has pretty generous free plan which allows you to create 5k links.

Indeed, Firebase Dynamic Links (FDL) have been a popular choice for developers to create deep links that can redirect users to specific content within their apps or to the appropriate app store for installation.
